# Advantage of using a smartfox server

Tags: web-server, gameserver

we are trying to outsource the server side of our game applicaton to someone. They recommend using http://www.smartfoxserver.com/ instead of our traditional php/mysql combination.

Our game is in actionscript and will be using social aspects of facebook later on. Smartfoxserver is supposed to reduce the time of development. The thing I'm having a hard time getting right now is how? How does it reduce the time.

We will still be making a RDMS writing stored procedures and game logic based server scripts. Where does smartfox come into play?

Thanks,
Fahim.

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow, imo

Answer (score 0):

SmartFoxServer provides high level features such as user management, room management, buddy list management, object serialization, automatic server updates and tons more.
All these would take months of coding to implement from scratch. Plus SmartFoxServer is highly scalable and can handle tens of thousands of concurrent players which would be impossible via PHP